# Next index value of object in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, foreach

i have this object called defined in my code as rates.rates:

```
{ AUD="1.4553",  BGN="1.9558",  BRL="3.5256"}
```

and i have the following $.each loop:

```
$.each( rates.rates, function( index, value ){

  console.log(index);

});
```

I've been trying without success to also console.log the next or the previous index (if they exist of course). Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can save the previous index in a variable. There's no way to get the next index.

Comment: Except that's poorly explained, why would you save the net index, for wich purpose? let us know, there is many possible answers depending on your final goal.

Comment: You can check the index against the total number of elements and 0 to see if they exists.

Comment: Your object syntax is wrong. It's `key: value`, not `key=value`

Comment: set a counter to 0 before the each, and then increment on each iteration of the each loop. This gives a pseudo-index for your loop.

Comment: @gavgrif and? like you said that's just a "pseudo" index, the OP dont want the next index itself, he want the element's value at the next index I tought.

Comment: @xoxel - oops I read it as wanting the numerical count of the items. I guess the only way to get teh actual elment would be to push each into an array and use standard array manipulation to get the elements at the previous and next position to the current index. Sorry - my mistake.

Comment: @xoxel, i can't understand why it's poorly explained. The scope of this code is to display a simple html table with rates, but i don't think it is required in order to understand the issue i am facing! Anyway, Solution of barmar sounds pretty good! Thank you all for your time!

Comment: @GeorgeR. don't take it for yourself, no problem by the way even if i didnt helped you at all, what i mean by "poorly explained" is "why do you not go any further in your explanations, what is your main goal, ect, 2 lines of explanations and some code are not enough for us too understand", anyway that's just MHO and i'am glad to know that you finally get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the object, get its keys as an array and iterate over that. Then you can add and subtract from the array index.

```
var keys = Object.keys(rates.rates);
$.each(keys, function(index, key) {
    var prevkey = index > 0 ? keys[index-1] : null;
    var nextkey = index < keys.length-1 ? keys[index+1] : null;
    console.log(prevkey, key, nextkey);
});
```

Comment: Best answer at the moment, just because it's what the OP's was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

JS objects have no defined order, they are (by definition) an unsorted set of key-value pairs.

But there's a way for you to do what you want.You can do it like this.

```
var keys=Object.keys(rates.rates);

for(vari=0; i<keys.length;i++)
{       
    console.log(i);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next or prev with `modulo`. With this you can make a loop automatically.

Please try below:

```js
rates={
    rates:{ "AUD":"1.4553",  "BGN":"1.9558",  "BRL":"3.5256"}
  };
var keys = Object.keys(rates.rates);
$.each(keys, function(index, key) {
    if(index == 0){index=keys.length};
    var prevkey = (index-1) % keys.length; 
    var nextkey = (index+1) % keys.length; 
    console.log(prevkey, key, nextkey);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```